# Can't find out how to resize website element

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my website. I started looking for websites to base my own on them. Now I get stuck, because I've found a nice menu bar, but I can't write it on my own. So, I've decided to copy it from the website ([website](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_41180/index.html)). The problem is, that I can't find where it is, or how the height  is defined. Whatever I did it is always 84px.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: The element is 18px and padding is 30 + 36 which adds up to 84. Right click the menu item in chrome and choose "Inspect Element" it shows you exactly where all these styles are defined (line 20 of superfish.css for the padding). Or use firebug or IE developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I started looking for the height: 84.
But nowhere to be found. At the height of the menu items affect paddings.

Recommend further use firebug or dragonfly or something else...

**superfish.css:15**

```
.menu > li > a {
...
padding: 30px 20px 36px;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well here's the code for the header (don't you just love the header tag?)

```
<header>
        <div class="header-pannel">
            <div class="inner-shadow">
                <div class="container_12 indent-bottom">
                    <div class="grid_12">
                        <!--======================== logo ============================-->
                        <h1><a href="index.html">Storex.</a></h1>
                        <!--=================== search form =====================-->
                        <form id="search-form" action="search.php" method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8">
                            <fieldset>
                                <label class="keywords">
                                    <input type="text" name="s" value="Search" onFocus="if(this.value =='Search' ) this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Search'">
                                </label>
                                <a onClick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit()"></a>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <!--======================== menu ============================-->
                <div class="border-top">
                    <div class="container_12">
                        <div class="grid_12">
                            <nav>
                                <ul class="menu responsive-menu">
                                    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index-1.html">Company</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Welcome Message</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Company Profile</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Our Capabilities</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Advantages</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Work Team</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Partnership</a></li>
                                                    <li class="last-item"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Our History</a></li>
                                            <li class="last-item"><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="index-2.html">Services</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index-3.html">Solutions</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index-4.html">Projects</a></li>
                                    <li class="last-item"><a href="index-5.html">Contacts</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

So that's pretty busy. I'd suggest looking in skeleton.css for most of the structural css elements.

My personal advice: if you are a novice, don't go looking at other sites. Most of them are crap (law of averages) and even if they look nice, the code can sometimes be atrocious. They aren't built with other coders in mind looking to take a pick and mix of elements, they are principally designed by the individual/ group/ company building the website with their own ease of use in mind (although, looking at the work produced by some professionals, I have no idea how they manage to maintain their code).

I'd suggest looking at frameworks. Particularly freely distributed ones. [Twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) would be a good example. Taking other peoples' code can also possibly infringe copywrite in some instances.

Comment: Thank you very much for recommendation. I will look at it.

Comment: Minor correction: unless stated otherwise, (in the US and in other countries), webpage code **IS** copyrighted. Review the [10 myths about copyright](http://www.templetons.com/brad/copymyths.html).